# Many to Many relation with extra column query Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I did a `@ManyToMany` relationship in Hibernate with an extra column successfully, as follows.

**Activity.class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Activity")
public class Activity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int actId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "pk.activity", 
            cascade = { CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.REMOVE })
    private Set<ActivityRepairMap> activityRepairMaps = new HashSet<ActivityRepairMap>();

    @NotEmpty
    private String actTurno;

    @NotEmpty
    private String actTexto;

    private String actFhc;    

    public Activity() {
    }    
    // Getters and Setters
}
```

**Repair.class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Repair2")
public class Repair {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int repId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "pk.repair")
    private Set<ActivityRepairMap> activityRepairMaps = new HashSet<ActivityRepairMap>();

    @NotEmpty(message=Constants.EMPTY_FIELD)
    private String repNombre;

    private Integer repCant;

    public Repair() {
    }    
    // Getters and Setters
}
```

**ActivityRepairMap.class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ActivityRepairMap")
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name="pk.activity", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="actId")),    
    @AssociationOverride(name="pk.repair", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="repId"))   
    })
public class ActivityRepairMap {

    private ActivityRepairId pk = new ActivityRepairId();
    private Integer actRepCant;

    @EmbeddedId
    public ActivityRepairId getPk() {
        return pk;
    }

    public void setPk(ActivityRepairId pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }

    @Transient
    public Activity getActivity() {
        return getPk().getActivity();
    }

    public void setActivity(Activity activity) {
        getPk().setActivity(activity);
    }

    @Transient
    public Repair getRepair() {
        return getPk().getRepair();
    }

    public void setRepair(Repair repair) {
        getPk().setRepair(repair);
    }

    @Column(name="actRepCant")
    public Integer getActRepCant() {
        return actRepCant;
    }

    public void setActRepCant(Integer actRepCant) {
        this.actRepCant = actRepCant;
    }

    public ActivityRepairMap (){

    }    
    // hashCode and equals methods
}
```

**ActivityRepairId**

```
@Embeddable
public class ActivityRepairId implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -776429030880521951L;
    private Activity activity;
    private Repair repair;

    @ManyToOne
    public Activity getActivity() {
        return activity;
    }

    public void setActivity(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    public Repair getRepair() {
        return repair;
    }

    public void setRepair(Repair repair) {
        this.repair = repair;
    }    
    // hashCode and equals method
}
```

My problem is that I can't query all the **repairs** used in a specific **activity**. 
I've already checked in MySQL Workbench that the data stored in the DB is correct.
I would appreciate if anyone can explain me either using HQL or Criteria how can I achieve this.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL this should be:

```
SELECT
  r.*
FROM 
  repair r
LEFT JOIN
  activity_repair ar 
    ON
      ar.repair_id = r.id
WHERE
  ar.activity_id = ?
```

Now it's still possible that a single `activity` is connected with two `repair`s, and though you might get some repairs twice in the result list. You could simple use a `SELECT DISTINCT r.*` to work around this, or work with a subquery.

In JPQL the query should be bascially the same as the SQL from above.

```
SELECT
  r
FROM 
  Repair r
WHERE
  r.activityRepairMaps.pk.activity = ?
```

If you need a JOIN:

```
SELECT
  r
FROM 
  Repair r
JOIN
  ActivityRepairMap arm
WHERE
  arm.pk.activity = ?
```

Maybe you need to use `@MapsId` within your ActivityRepairMaps class. (I haven't done JPQL for a while now)

As a far as I remember, you should NOT use Entities within your `@EmbeddedId` classes, but instead use the raw `@Id` type of the corresponding classes. Instead of `Repair` and `Activity`, you should use `int` and `int`.